# how do i fix the "module not found" error in auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyautogui, auto-py-to-exe

im making an autoclicker just to mess around, and when i package it with auto-py-to-exe it exports but when i try running it normally it just crashes. when i run the .exe from cmd (with the path) this error comes up:

```
C:\Users\[myname]>"C:\Users\[myname]\OneDrive\desktop\autoclicker\dist\autoclicker.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoclicker.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
[12716] Failed to execute script 'autoclicker' due to unhandled exception!

C:\Users\[myname]>
```

CODE:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import sys
print("Just hold R to stat clicking!")
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("R"):
        pyautogui.click()
```

i tried to fix it by renaming the file, putting it in my D:\ drive and reinstalling python AND pyautogui, also tried reinstalling auto-py-to-exe and tried exporting it with pyinstaller. still same problem

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me using pyinstaller.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create empty directory and `cd {emptydirectoryname}`
2. create `main.py` and paste your code into it but add an execution guard such as :

`main.py`

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Just hold R to stat clicking!")
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("R"):
            pyautogui.click()
```

3. create a virtual environment `python -m venv venv`
4. activate virtual environment `venv\scripts\activate`
5. install dependencies `pip install pyinstaller keyboard pyautogui`
6. do a quick test run of the script to make sure it's all installed correctly
7. `pyinstaller -F main.py`
8. once it is finished execute the compiled app with `dist\main.exe`  and bobs your uncle